# application crashes when adding user control within an other user control in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am new to WPF. I have 1 main windows and 3 user Controls say standard, moderate, professional. 
I add standard in moderate and professional user control, also add standard in mainWindow to view its button. and switching between mode on button click.
App is getting crash as soon it start and error nullreference, and when I comment  (in main window) then app work and start with no error.
In mainWindow, moderate and professional added

```
xmlns:customControl="clr-namespace:Cal_C"
```

and in mainWindow grid

```
<customControl:standardPage Grid.Row="3"/>
```

Similarly in moderate and Professional user control added as well. 
At runtime I got this error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

If I Commented user control at main window then it work fine otherwise it give error. plz help me in this. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, provide a [code](http://sscce.org/) that fails and an error. Also, suggest to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic not to recieve fast downvotes and question-close on SO ;)

Comment: In mainWindow, moderate and professional added 
xmlns:customControl="clr-namespace:Cal_C"
and in grid of mainWindow
<customControl:standardPage Grid.Row="3"/>
Similarly in moderate and Professional user control added as well
<customControl:standardPage/>
At runtime I got this error 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: If I Commented user control at main window then it work fine otherwise it give error

Comment: Ok, it should be not in comments, but in the post! Use "edit" link under your question. Then insert and format your code: 1) select all the code and press **`{}`** button OR 2)  indent every line with 4 spaces manually. OR 3) you also could use backticks \`\` to highlight **one line** of code)

Comment: I just added these two lines and for testing in each user control I placed 1 textblock and 1 button. and calling them on mainWindow on button click. that's all.

Comment: `StackOverflowException` is definitely for **Stack Overflow** ;)